# Align left or right using a variable in .format()

Tags: python-3.x, variables, string.format

Make a variable, item, that points to a string, "car". Make a variable, cost, that points to 13499.99. Print out a line that has item in a left-justified area of 10 characters, and cost in a right-justified area of 10 characters with 2 decimal places and commas in the thousands place.

```
item = "car"
cost = 99,999.99
print('{:<10} {:>10}'.format(item, cost))
```

essentially this is the desired output
car       13,499.99

Clearly I am doing something wrong here...
From what I can tell this is what I need to do to achieve the desired effect. I am new to coding and Stack Overflow so if this question has been answered, I apologize. If somebody could help me out, I would greatly appreciate it. Also this is python 3.5.

Comment: That is because the assignment `cost = 99,999.99` assigns a tuple `(99, 999.99)` to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues with your code:

1) cost variable should be a number rather than a string i.e. 99999.99 (the comma formatting can be applied with .format()

2) the print statement should be as below

```
>>>item = "car"
>>>cost = 99999.99
>>>print('{:<10} {:>10,.2f}'.format(item, cost))
car         99,999.99
```

Comment: Thank you for  the answer. This is a low level question and I appreciate you giving me an answer someone of low level knowledge can understand!

Comment: very welcome @JacobRay - hope it helps. Please upvote the answer if you find it useful. Thanks!